# How to get iframe content from a remote page?

Tags: php, jquery, parsing, iframe, simple-html-dom

I think PHP is useless, bacause iframe is inserted after php is executed, or am I wrong?

So, the only solution I am aware of is to use Javascript/jQuery.

E.g. this would work if the JS would be on the same page as a the iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    var myContent = $("#iFrame").contents().find("#myContent")
  });

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="mifile.html" id="iFrame" style="width:200px;height:70px;border:dotted 1px red" frameborder="0">
     <div id="myContent">
        iframe content blablabla
     </div>
  </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

However I am using Simple HTML DOM library to grab the distant webpage like:

```
$url = 'http://page-with-some-iframe.com/';
            $html = file_get_html( $url );

            // Find iframes and put them in an array
            $iframes_arr = array();
            foreach($html->find('iframe') as $element) {
                $iframes_arr[] = $element->outertext;
            }
var_dump($iframes_arr);
die();
```

But obviously, nothing is returned ;(, because iframes are displayed after php is run ;(

So, I was thinking that I would probably need to inject this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    var myContent = $("#iFrame").contents().find("#myContent")
  });

</script>
```

in the header of my grabbed page stored in $html.

Any idea how to get iframe content like that or is this too complicated approach and some easier solution does exist?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is AJAX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to access the document of a remote page inside an iframe using javascript because of the same origin policy.

If you know the URL of the page you can use PHP CURL to retrieve it

```
<?php 
        // Initialise a cURL object
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // Set url and other options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://page-with-some-iframe.com");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // Get the page contents
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: and even if javascript could get the contents, PHP does not execute the javascript so that is not possible either

Comment: if CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER set to true, the curl_exec return false. How to grabe content if CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER set to false ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible because of security policy.
If you are able to get contents of remote iframe - you can steal someone's facebook or banking data with ease. Thats why all web browsers blocks this.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this is very secure. E.g. I can get the content of the iframe like: `foreach($detail_page_url_html->find('div.entry iframe') as $element) {
      $iframes_arr[] = $element->src;
    }`

Comment: Yeah, but you get it as you, with your cookies, your ip, your useragent, not the site visitor. And you get only initial src which was in source html of the page

Comment: Yeah, but I can use that URL and parse it in the next step (foreach loop). I can set also the header, useragent in curl. Not sure about IP and cookies though ;) I am only a beginner in PHP.

Comment: You cannot access any data which users browser got in iframe. Its more likely you guess password then you guess all cookies. Not that lots of sites also validates user-agent (which you can set) and ip (which you can not set).

Comment: So you probably discovered the most dangerous vulnerability in your browser. As I said it is not possible. You can get contents of the page, but AS YOU (SEPARATE PHP REQUEST), not as a person who opens the page. The only execption is when both pages are on the same domain.

Comment: How, can firebug do that? I can see via firebug the iframe content

Comment: But firebug is on YOUR computer, so its YOUR request. I am repeating this for the 5th time. ONLY USER WHO OPENS the page can access iframes in it. Firebug = you = access. Javascript on parent page = not you = no access