# How to access IFrame in php

Tags: php, iframe

I have one website,from that website i want to download `iframe` contain.

that is

```
<iframe frameborder="no" align="center" width="100%" height="500px" style="width: 100%; height: 500px" name="FRAME1" src="/CWRWeb/nova/jsp/reports/running.jsp"></iframe>
```

In this iframe data is present.

Using `PHP Scriptable Web Browser` i am able to get that page. but i am not able to access iframe data.

so i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668111/how-to-get-iframe-content-from-a-remote-page) but i not got.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('simpletest/browser.php');

$browser = new SimpleBrowser();
$browser->get('https://www.mywebsite.com');
$browser->setField('userID', 'abc');
$browser->setField('passwd', 'abc123');
$log=$browser->click('login');





$browser->setCookie('xx','12345'); 
$browser->setCookie('pqr','dsw1278');

echo $log; /* suceessful login */

/* next page which has paremeter to be set */
$parameters = array (
"fromMonth"=>"NOV",
"fromDay"=>"05",
"fromYear"=>"2013",
"toMonth"=>"NOV",
"toDay"=>"05",
"toYear"=>"2013",

);


$browser->post('https://www.xxxx.com/Web/download.do?',$parameters); /*page where iframe is present */

/* here i want to access my iframe so i used */

$ch = curl_init(); 

        // Set url and other options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"/CWRWeb/nova/jsp/reports/running.jsp");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // Get the page contents
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        echo $output;

        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        curl_close($ch);  

?>
```

can any one tell me which is the best way to get iframe data.

Comment: Fetch the URL of the iframe which is in the `src` attribute.

Comment: @ TiMESPLiNTER i tried. its shows blank page.

Comment: @ TiMESPLiNTER i have added my code please take a look. thank you.

Comment: What does `echo $output;` print out?

Comment: I dont understand if this url (/CWRWeb/nova/jsp/reports/running.jsp) is another domain or same domain. if another, then you should use complete url with cURL. see: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try the get option in PHP.

```
<?php
$data = $_GET['YOUR_IFRAME_URL'];
// OR
$data = file_get_contents('YOUR_IFRAME_URL');

echo $data; //string output
?>
```

Comment: when i tried above code its giving me                                         Notice: Undefined index: /CWRWeb/nova/jsp/reports/running.jsp

Comment: Are you using the full URL with "http and www"? (like "http : // www . example.com/mypage.jsp") (remove the spaces)

Comment: ya.i am using like this.  https://www.xxx.com/Web/Sum.do                i used davidwalsh.name/curl-download . it giving me Object not found!

Comment: Ok.. this should work: file_get_contents('YOUR_IFRAME_URL'). save this to some variable and echo it. I have edited my answer also.

Comment: i used file_get_contents('https://www.xxx.com/Web/nova/jsp/reports/running.jsp'). but same error.

Comment: you can try file_get_contents with other url and see how it works. is there anything wrong with that url you are trying?

Comment: for other url it is working. but not working for Iframe url. what is the problem ? can you please guide me.

Comment: seems like it has something to do with the url you are using.

Comment: then how to get to know what all it is using.